# oAuth style NSURLRequst with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, file-upload, oauth

I have an app that uses a 2 leg oAuth on our PHP server. We parse the php://input stream curently to get the signature params and raw post data. However according to php.net you can't use input stream with multipart form data so when I try to send an image from the iPhone to server the php://input stream is empty.

Here's my question being new to Oath rules and what not.

Is it required that you use the input stream vs reading from $POST super global?
Can I send the signature and image in the same call like

```
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];


[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"signature"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[postVars dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];


[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"tester.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I've seen some suggestions to set the Authorization header with the signature params. Is it correct to send signature in the post body or set the authorization headers? Also Am I way off in how to upload and image using oAuth? Does it need to be 2 calls or can I do signature and image in same calls?

Thanks for the help. We are using this to send data from iPhone to our server so we wrote both sides but want to follow oAuth best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oauth prefers the oauth params set in the authorization header ([see here](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#consumer_req_param)).  Everything that the provider expects should be in that header, including a signature that's formed by signing the verb, the url, post parameters, various oauth params, etc., lexically ordered.

The rest of the request can be whatever you want, like an image post, multipart or not.

Comment: currently our API on our server reads the signature info from php://input stream. Should it read the signature on the server end from the authorization header? since the input stream will be empty when sending an image?

Comment: I think so.  I think the client should set the oauth stuff in the request header and the server should expect to find it there.

Comment: Looks like according to oAuth 1.0 you don't include images in the signature base so this way should work fine. I'll set the `Authorization` header then send my file in the post

Answer (score 0):

@danh Gave me the answer I needed but I just wanted to expand upon it.

In iOS I set the Authorization header 
`[request setValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

This header contains a JSON string of my signature, appid, timestamp etc.

I generate the signature from all my params except my image file. OAuth says you generate the signature base from URLEncode content-types so since Images are not URLEncode types you dont have to use any part of them in your signature base. This means you can then send your image and any params you did use in the signature as part of the POST body.

Mine looks like this

```
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"data"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imagename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

On my server I can parse the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header to get my oAuth values, use the $_POST to get my params and $_FILES to get my images. All of which still follows oAuth guidelines. Thanks for the help.